# Unable to find solution for the strange exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, uwp

I'm creating a UWP app. Here I faced one exception which was thrown continuously. Here we hosted the API in IIS by using ASP.NET. UWP app was created using the Xamarin forms and C#.

And also we also integrate the scanner service with the UWP app by using the WCF.

I don't know how to solve this exception. There was no stack trace was available. Also unable to decode this exception. Please give some ideas and suggest a way to solve this exception. Thanks in advance!!!

```
Message: System.Exception: {
  "SCID": "023",
  "UserID": "944",
  "InputObj": {
    "Message": "Excep_FromHResult 0x80072EFF",
    "Data": {},
    "InnerException": null,
    "HelpLink": null,
    "Source": "<unknown>",
    "HResult": -2147012865,
    "StackTrace": "   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4a0ad0\r\n   
at Supervisor!<BaseAddress>+0x103f7f2\r\n   
at Supervisor!<BaseAddress>+0x103f6ac\r\n   
at Supervisor!<BaseAddress>+0x103f638\r\n   
at Supervisor!<BaseAddress>+0x10a4c35\r\n   
at Supervisor!<BaseAddress>+0x10a4fbd\r\n   
at Supervisor!<BaseAddress>+0x10a3154\r\n   
at System.IO.Stream.<>c__DisplayClass9.<ReadAsyncTask>b__10()\r\n   
at System.Func<System.Int32>.Invoke()\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x5911a5\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4f518c\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5c60\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5be8\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5ba7\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x50cdaf\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x50df3d\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5c60\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5be8\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5ba7\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x50cdaf\r\n   
at Supervisor!<BaseAddress>+0xff8da9\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5c60\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5be8\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5ba7\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x54529b\r\n   
at Supervisor!<BaseAddress>+0xab10c5\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5c60\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5be8\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5ba7\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x54529b\r\n   
at Supervisor!<BaseAddress>+0xab1f74\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5c60\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5be8\r\n   
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4d5ba7\r\n   
at Supervisor!<BaseAddress>+0xe2bead"
  }
}
 Stack Trace:
```

Comment: Which scanner library are you using?

Comment: Do you know when will the error happen?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Sorry, I don't know when this error happened, not able to trace this error

Comment: @Anand Extremely, sorry for the delay, we are using Zebra scanner

Comment: Well, it's hard to locate where the issue is. I'd suggest you narrow down the issue by testing part of the functions first.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Thanks!!! But while testing, it is very hard to find this exception.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you test this? For example, just test the connection with IIS first and make sure it works. Then try to test with WCF. So you could know if the problem is related to WCF or the IIS.

Comment: Would you suggest modifying the catch, I believe when it catches multiple exception at same time this is causing a issue.  --@RoyLi-MSFT

Comment: @Anand we are not using any scanner library.